# Calculating weekly worked hours, including months with 5 Saturdays

Tags: contracts, overtime, hours

There are a couple of issues/mistakes in my contract, one of which states that I shall work 29 hours per week. However, I am scheduled to work Tuesday, Thursday, Friday and two Saturdays a month. Saturday working hours are from 11am-6pm and all other days 11am-7pm.

3 days at 8 hours is **24 hours**

If I calculate on the basis of 4 Saturdays a month, my calculation is 14 hours / 4 weeks, which comes out at **3.5 hours p/week**.

So, in theory I should only be working **27.5** as opposed to **29 hours**, in writing.

I am getting a flat monthly fee, so I am trying to calculate how many overtime hours I am working, but at the current calculation I am consistently under-time even when I work all the full days I am supposed to work.

**My question is, seeing as there are some months with 5 Saturdays and some with 4, is my calculation correct? Is there a calculation that is used in HR to determine what that hourly work rate should be?**

Comment: You could always ask your HR what they think your hourly rate is. That's possibly safer than drawing their attention to the discrepancy in hours directly. But it sounds like you're not working any overtime, so this is fairly moot? And if you're being paid a flat fee I assume you're not paid for overtime anyway?

Comment: The calculation to use should be legally defined for each country and can vary by how an employee is classified. Ask HR or look it up for your situation.

Comment: @antonanton is it possible that you get half an hour of payed lunch on workdays and that is supposed to fill the 1.5 hour gap? note: that saterday is not a workday.

Comment: @antonanton why are you talking about overhours? People usually don't make overhours when working the days they are supposed to.

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: If you are scheduled to come in at 11:00 AM and you leave at 6:00 PM, are you sure this counts as 8 hours worked? What about break times? How is this counted? Do you and HR agree on your method of counting working time for a given day? Also, you didn't consider that the time you're scheduled may be a minimum. Maybe you're expected to stay late sometimes (but no more than an average of 29 hours per week for example).

Comment: @RaoulMensink, there are plenty of occupations/industries where Saturday is a work day, and not always with any special considerations.  Retail, hospitality and manufacturing quickly come to mind.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, this is not about overtime pay or lunch or what not. It is simply trying to make a calculation for the months where you have a 5th saturday.. Thank you @anketam that seems to have been what the accountant used.

Comment: It would seem wise to check your calculations very very careful, check your payment calculation very very careful, and if you think you are being overpaid then decide that HR in your company is a lot better than you with that kind of calculation and be very quiet about it :-)

Comment: Possibility is that you are paid 50% overtime on saturdays, and everything works out exactly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It could be the fifth Saturday in the month**

Assuming they were including the partial week into the month there are a few ways it can be calculated for example:
52.14 weeks in a year or 4.14 extra weeks, but only half of which you will work that extra Saturday.  2.07 extra Saturdays / 12 months * 7 hours ends being an extra 1.21 hours, or a total of 28.71 hours.  If they rounded it up you get 29 hours.